# SELECT PHP and MySQL not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-num-rows

I have this code for the select and printing values.
mysql_numn_rows returns null :/

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db("db2517");



$username = "Cristoforo";
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * users WHERE username='$username' ");

$numberOfRows = mysql_num_rows($query);
echo "num: $numberOfRows";


?>
```

Comment: forgot to add from after *, select * from users .........

Comment: query should be like = mysql_query("SELECT * from users WHERE username='$username' ");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better use mysqli or pdo instead of mysql.here you missed `from` in your query so your Query should be

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * from users WHERE username='$username' ");
```

Comment: is your connection is okie?

Comment: `*` is present in the question

Comment: @Cristoforo:Please check whether your connection is okie or not?

Answer (score 1):

First I would like to suggest you user [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MYQLI](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

In your query you have missed the `from` so replace your query:

From

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * users WHERE username='$username' ");
```

To

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * from users WHERE username='$username' ");
```